# Counterpart of stencil update in other languages

Tags: fortran, programming-languages

What I find really interesting is Fortrans's capability of stencil updates: instead of looping

```
t2 = v(1)
do i=2, n-1
    t1   = v(i)
    v(i) = 0.5 * (t2 + v(i+1))
    t2   = t1
enddo
```

one can use a one-liner, without an explicit loop

```
v(2:n-1) = 0.5 * (v(1:n-2) + v(3:n))
```

(For this, and other examples see [this slideshow](https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/documents/13601/162125/fortran_class.pdf))

I haven't anything similar in any other programming language. Is there any other language which supports a similar syntax?

Comment: What is "it" in your first sentence? The Fortran language? Off the top of my head, MATLAB does this too.

Comment: @Ross, fixed that "it"

Comment: Python, Chapel, Julia, everyone can answer  with his favourite language. Voting to close as too broad, because *"There are either too many possible answers"*

Comment: Cilkplus array notation is or was similar enough to be confusing. I thought the Fortran notation had antecedents.

Comment: Before Fortran 90/95 there was High Performance Fortran.

Comment: What's the syntax in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @VladimirF: I think that HPF actually post-dates Fortran 90.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be interesting to check the wiki page for [Array programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming), which says

> Modern programming languages that support array programming are commonly used in scientific and engineering settings; these include Fortran 90, Mata, MATLAB, Analytica, TK Solver (as lists), Octave, R, Cilk Plus, Julia, and the NumPy extension to Python...

and also pages for [array slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing) and [a list of array languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Array_language). So, several languages seem to have a similar syntax (which goes back to as old as ALGOL68 ?!)

Here are some examples (there may be mistakes so please check by yourself..):

Fortran :

```
program main
    implicit none
    real, allocatable :: v(:)
    integer i, n

    n = 8
    v = [( real(i)**2, i=1,n )]
    print *, "v = ", v

    v(2:n-1) = 0.5 * ( v(1:n-2) + v(3:n) )
    print *, "v = ", v
end

$ gfortran test.f90 && ./a.out
 v =    1.00000000       4.00000000       9.00000000       16.0000000       25.0000000       36.0000000       49.0000000       64.0000000    
 v =    1.00000000       5.00000000       10.0000000       17.0000000       26.0000000       37.0000000       50.0000000       64.0000000
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np

n = 8
v = np.array( [ float(i+1)**2 for i in range( n ) ] )
print( "v = ", v )

v[1:n-1] = 0.5 * ( v[0:n-2] + v[2:n] )
print( "v = ", v )

$ python3 test.py 
v =  [  1.   4.   9.  16.  25.  36.  49.  64.]
v =  [  1.   5.  10.  17.  26.  37.  50.  64.]
```

Julia:

```
n = 8
v = Float64[ i^2 for i = 1 : n ]
println( "v = ", v )

v[2:n-1] = 0.5 * ( v[1:n-2] + v[3:n] )
println( "v = ", v )

$ julia test.jl
v = [1.0,4.0,9.0,16.0,25.0,36.0,49.0,64.0]
v = [1.0,5.0,10.0,17.0,26.0,37.0,50.0,64.0]
```

Chapel:

```
var n = 8;
var v = ( for i in 1..n do (i:real)**2 );
writeln( "v = ", v );

var vtmp = 0.5 * ( v[1..n-2] + v[3..n] );
v[2..n-1] = vtmp;
writeln( "v = ", v );

$ chpl test.chpl && ./a.out
v = 1.0 4.0 9.0 16.0 25.0 36.0 49.0 64.0
v = 1.0 5.0 10.0 17.0 26.0 37.0 50.0 64.0
```

(please see wiki pages etc for other languages).

I think the array notation such as `:` or `..` is very convenient, but it can give unexpected results (if not used properly, e.g., the meaning of indices, or a possible overlap of LHS/RHS) or cause run-time overhead (because of temporary arrays), depending on cases. So please take care when actually using it...